# How to disable button with Response Redirect

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, button

I Have two pages, Pages A and Pages B, in Pages A i have button which one will redirect to Pages B, then i try to back to Page A using button from browser.
Please your suggestion, how i can disable my button in Page A for not redirect again to Pages B.

Comment: Which Button browser back button or asp.net button

Comment: @ Tanmay Nehete, asp.button sir.. so prevent to redirect to page B

Comment: Is there any condition to disable the button?

Comment: I have a signup page, after filling the detail of the Signup page it redirect to detail page with create a session of the User name.
if user again want to move signup page from the detail page on click of back botton of the browoser then it should not be possible.it again redirect to detail page...
So How is it  possible.
Please tell me the way..

Comment: Updated the post. You can check now.

Answer (score 0):

OK. If you want to disable the browser's back button feature, then you can try the below `JavaScript`: Put it in the head tag of the Sign Up page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function noBack() { window.history.forward() }
    noBack();
    window.onload = noBack;
    window.onpageshow = function (evt) { if (evt.persisted) noBack() }
    window.onunload = function () { void (0) }
</script>
```

**Note**: This will only block the feature of browser's back button but if you manually go back to the Sign Up page writing in the address bar, this then will not work.

One more thing, as you are using `Session`, you can integrate it with the `JavaScript` as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var someVar = "Hello";
   //var someVar = <%=this.Session["UserId"]%>; //Keeping the session value in JavaScript variable
   function noBack() {
      if (someVar == "Hello") { //You can use - if (someVar != null)
       window.history.forward()
     }
   }
   noBack();
   window.onload = noBack;
   window.onpageshow = function (evt) { if (evt.persisted) noBack() }
   window.onunload = function () { void (0) }
</script>
```